# Trying to add duplicates within a list of lists in order

Tags: python, loops, duplicates

I have two separate lists within a list.. I am trying to count duplicates within the second list. I can do it from list a to list b, with the result:

```
count_list = [['about', 1], ['almost', 1], ['apple', 1], ['break', 1], ['Singapore', 1], ['cider', 1], ['up', 1], ['day', 1]]
first_proc_count = [['turn', 1], ['there', 1], ['pear', 1], ['up', 1], ['XXXXXX', 0], ['drink', 1], ['near', 1], ['up', 1]]

for word in first_proc_count:  
    for word2 in count_list:
        if word[0] == word2[0]:
            word[1] = word[1] + word2[1]
            word2[1] = 0  


print(count_list)
print(first_proc_count)
```

with the result
-[['about', 1], ['almost', 1], ['apple', 1], ['break', 1], ['Singapore', 1], ['cider', 1], ['up', 0], ['day', 1]]
-[['turn', 1], ['there', 1], ['pear', 1], ['up', 2], ['XXXXXX', 0], ['drink', 1], ['near', 1], ['up', 1]]

with the word “up” being added to 2nd list and “up” being set to 0 in the first.

But I am having a problem doing the same within the second list ie. with a single list. I know I should increment the loop by one and look in the incremented loop. The result I would hope for is:

[['turn', 1], ['there', 1], ['pear', 1], ['up', 3], ['XXXXXX', 0], ['drink', 1], ['near', 1], ['up', 0]]

I have tried  a range and length with an += 1 but I’m getting nowhere. First ever question here. Excuse the bad formatting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the problem is that you're comparing the list to itself twice over. The following code should fix this:

```
count_list = [['about', 1], ['almost', 1], ['apple', 1], ['break', 1], ['Singapore', 1], ['cider', 1], ['up', 1], ['day', 1]]
first_proc_count = [['turn', 1], ['there', 1], ['pear', 1], ['up', 1], ['XXXXXX', 0], ['drink', 1], ['near', 1], ['up', 1]]

for i in range(len(first_proc_count)):
    for word2 in first_proc_count[i + 1:]:
        if first_proc_count[i][0] == word2[0]:
            first_proc_count[i][1] = first_proc_count[i][1] + word2[1]
            word2[1] = 0

print(count_list)
print(first_proc_count)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew there was a +1 but had it in the wrong place, and without the colon.